# Count all duplicates items and determine average time of each duplicate ocurrance of array of strings

Tags: c#

I have an array that contains data as follows (string and time data separated by a comma):

array[0]= Channel 1, 01:05:36

array[1]= Channel 2, 02:25:36

array[2]= Group 1, 22:25:36

array[3]= Netwk, 41:40:09

array[4]= LossOf, 03:21:17

array[5]= LossOf, 01:13:28

array[6]= Channel 1, 04:25:36

array[7]= Channel 2, 00:25:36

.
.
.
array[xxx]= xxx, xxx

I would like to count all duplicates items and determine average time for each duplicate found as follows:

Item1,  Channel 1, 2 occurrences, average time for each occurrence is about xx minutes

Item2,  Channel 2, 2 occurrences, average time for each occurrence is about xx minutes

Item3,  LossOf, 2 occurrences, average time for each occurrence is about xx minutes

The time format is hh:mm:ss

This is what I have done so far, which only gives me total times of duplicates:

```
public void CountDuplicates(string[] myStringArray)
{
  //count duplicates
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
  int  loopCnt=0;

  foreach (string item in myStringArray)
  {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStringArray[loopCnt]) == true)
      list.Add(item);
    loopCnt++;
  }

  loopCnt = 0;
  Dictionary<string, int> distinctItems = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  foreach (string item in list)
  {
    if (!distinctItems.ContainsKey(item))
    {
      distinctItems.Add(item, 0);
      loopCnt++;
    }
    distinctItems[item] += 1;
  }
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> distinctItem in distinctItems)
  {
    txtDisplayResults.AppendText("Alarm Error: " + distinctItem.Key + ",  How many times: " + distinctItem.Value + "\r\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What part is giving you problems (this isn't a code-writing service, it's a Q&A site :))?

Comment: You've added a comment about some data has invalid time values (i.e. just comments) could you confirm what the behaviour in this case needs to be?

Comment: Please explain in detail what it is you want to do, what you have tried and what is or isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

a channel class to hold your values

```
class Channel
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}
```

your sample data

```
var array = new[]{
    "Channel 1, 01:05:36",
    "Channel 2, 02:25:36",
    "Group 1, 22:25:36",
    "Network, 41:40:09",
    "Loss of, 03:21:17",
    "Loss of, 01:13:28",
    "Channel 1, 04:25:36",
    "Channel 2, 00:25:36",
};
```

the query

```
var channelGroups = array.Select(s =>
{
    var tokens = s.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var tsTokens = tokens[1].Split(':');
    return new Channel()
    {
        Name = tokens[0],
        Duration = new TimeSpan(
            int.Parse(tsTokens[0]),  // hours
            int.Parse(tsTokens[1]),  // minutes
            int.Parse(tsTokens[2]))  // seconds
    };
})
.GroupBy(c => c.Name)
.Select(g => new
{
    Channel = g.Key,
    Count = g.Count(),
    Average = g.Average(c => c.Duration.TotalMinutes)
});
```

output:

```
foreach(var group in channelGroups)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Channel:[{0}] Count:[{1}] Average:[{2}]"
                    , group.Channel, group.Count, group.Average);
}
```

demo: http://ideone.com/6dF6s

```
Channel:[Channel 1] Count:[2] Average:[165.6]
Channel:[Channel 2] Count:[2] Average:[85.6]
Channel:[Group 1] Count:[1] Average:[1345.6]
Channel:[Network] Count:[1] Average:[2500.15]
Channel:[Loss of] Count:[2] Average:[137.375]
```

Comment: `Timespan.ParseExact` will crap out on `41:40:09` it requires hours to be 0-23

Comment: @BobVale: Corrected, had to use the contructor and the ugly `string.split` to intialize the `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your help and very complete example, which is provides the right results every time.

Answer (score 0):

something like to following help?

```
var regex=new Regex(@"^(?<item>.*), (?<hours>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})$");
var result=array.Select(a=> regex.Match(a)).Where(a=>a.Success)
           .Select (a => new { 
                               item=a.Groups["item"].Value,
                               time=decimal.Parse(a.Groups["hours"].Value)*60 + 
                                    decimal.Parse(a.Groups["minutes"].Value) +
                                    decimal.Parse(a.Groups["seconds"].Value)/60
                              })
           .GroupBy (a => a.item)
           .Select (a =>new {item=a.Key, duplicates=a.Count(),time=a.Average (b => b.time)} );
```

to format as a string you can then do:

```
var resultString=result.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),(sb,a)=>sb.AppendFormat("Item: {0}, # of occurences: {1}, Average Time: {2:0.00}\r\n",a.item,a.duplicates,a.time)).ToString();
```

`resultString` will now be the string you are looking for.

EDIT -- After request to use a dictionary, as tuple is unavailable you need to define a class to hold the temporary data. I've used pulbic fields but you could easily expand to use properties round private fields

```
public class Data { 
   public int Occurrences;
   public decimal Time;

   public Data(int occurrences, decimal time) {
     this.Occurrences=occurrences;
     this.Time=time;
   }
}

var regex=new Regex(@"^(?<item>.*), (?<hours>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})$");
var dict = new Dictionary<string,Data>();

foreach (var entry in array) {
    if (regex.IsMatch(entry)) {
      var match=regex.Match(entry);
      var item=match.Groups["item"].Value;
      var time=decimal.Parse(match.Groups["hours"].Value)*60 + 
                                        decimal.Parse(match.Groups["minutes"].Value) +
                                        decimal.Parse(match.Groups["seconds"].Value)/60;
      if (dict.ContainsKey(item)) {
        dict[item].Occurrences++;
                dict[item].Time+=time);
      } else {
        dict[item]=new Data(1,time);
      }
    }
}

StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
foreach (var key in dict.Keys) {
    sb.AppendFormat("Item: {0}, # of occurences: {1}, Average Time: {2:0.00}\r\n", key, dict[key].Occurrences, dict[key].Time / dict[key].Occurrences);
}
var resultString=sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Bob, How could I display these values with         txtDisplayResults.AppendText("Item: " + a.Key + ",  # of occurrences : " + a.Count + ",  Average Time: " + a.Average + "\r\n");
Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer, not the `{2:0.00}` simply formats the time to 2 decimal places, you can use alternative formats for differing decimal places if you want

Comment: Hi Bob and Tim,
I have tried both approaches and they work great!

How will I handle a situation when data on array is not time format but a string: 
array[0]= Channel 1, 01:05:36
array[1]= Channel 2, 02:25:36
array[2]= Group 1,  abc

Both approaches give me an error as they expect a time format string (“:”).  Could you please advice changes to code as to handle a mix of time format and a string such as “abc”. 

Thanks again,

frn

Comment: frn what do you want the behaviour to be?

Comment: Bob, is ok I will do the filtering prior to executing above code.  Is it too much involve to create a solution similar to above with "Dictionary<string, int>"?  Thanks again.  frn

Comment: @frn yes its possible, what do you want as the string and what as the int?

Comment: Bob, I am sorry for the confusion about the string and int.  I am asking about a solution with "Dictionary<string, ???>" as a replacement for your above solution (LinQ). Thanks.

Comment: @frn a little confused to exactly what you are after with the Dictionary.  You want a solution that outputs a dictionary as a result (which can be achieved using the `ToDictionary()` extension) or you want a solution that makes use of a dictionary to achieve the same answer

Comment: Bob, I want a solution that makes use of a dictionary to achieve the same answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @frn Updated solution to include a dictionary based solution

Comment: Bob, I cannot test this code as Tuple is not available on VS2008.  Do you have another option?  Thanks.

Comment: @frn Done, you will have to use a helper class

Comment: Hi Bob, I tried all 3 solutions: both from you and the one from Tim Schmelter; and the later one was the most accurate: Channel 1 Disabled,  Count: 14 Vs Channel: Channel 1 Disabled,  Count: 6. I really appreciate your time and effort on this request, and I am going to use Tim Schmelter solution as being right in the money every time.  Thanks again.